# How to Make Indexing process Async. in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sql, reindex, async

I am using Indexing process in Magento 2.
I have 60 Million products and when i run indexer it just struck in processing from past 4 days.
When i check indexer status on sow processlist it will run only one query.

Is it any way to make the indexer Asynchronous means multiple queries will be runnin at one time so multiple product will be re-indexed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage with 60m products? Is this your new store?

I don't think Magento can handle this many products, displaying it to customers is already a problem.
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048176832-Best-practice-Magento-number-of-categories-limits